# Wordpress PHP помогите пожалуйста. Узнать, как добраться к "Price 4H: 2550"

Tags: php, wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте,
Купил тему на wordpress и не могу разобраться, что отвечает за "Price 4H: 2550". Как не пытался не могу удалить, но мне его перенести на фотку. Буду рад если поможете!

```
    <?php
/* add_ons_php */

//$azp_attrs,$azp_content,$azp_element
$azp_mID = $el_id = $el_class = $images_to_show = $hide_address = $hide_excerpt = $hide_features = $hide_cats = $hide_price_range = 
$hide_contacts = $hide_view_map = $hide_gallery = $hide_footer = $show_price = $show_locations = $show_web = $disable_address_url = '';
$num_feature = $show_pricerange = '';
// var_dump($azp_attrs);
extract($azp_attrs);

$classes = array(
    'azp_element',
    'preview_listing_content',
    'azp-element-' . $azp_mID,
    'geodir-category-content',
    $el_class,
);
// $animation_data = self::buildAnimation($azp_attrs);
// $classes[] = $animation_data['trigger'];
// $classes[] = self::buildTypography($azp_attrs);//will return custom class for the element without dot
// $azplgallerystyle = self::buildStyle($azp_attrs);

$classes = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', implode( ' ', array_filter( $classes ) ) );

if($el_id!=''){
    $el_id = 'id="'.$el_id.'"';
}
$website = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), ESB_META_PREFIX.'website', true );
$latitude = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), ESB_META_PREFIX.'latitude', true );
$longitude = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), ESB_META_PREFIX.'longitude', true );
$address_url = '#';
if( $disable_address_url != 'yes' && !empty($latitude) && !empty($longitude) ) $address_url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query='.esc_attr($latitude).','.esc_attr($longitude);

// if(has_post_thumbnail( )){ ?>
<div class="<?php echo $classes; ?>" <?php echo $el_id;?>>

    
    <div class="geodir-category-content-title fl-wrap">
        <div class="geodir-category-content-title-item">
            <h3 class="title-sin_map">
                <?php if( $GLOBALS['is_lad'] ) echo '<span class="litem-ad">'.__( 'AD', 'townhub-add-ons' ).'</span>'; ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(  ); ?>"><?php 
                    the_title(); 
                    // $title = get_the_title( get_the_ID() );
                    // echo substr($title, 0, 100);
                ?></a>
                <?php if( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), ESB_META_PREFIX.'verified', true ) == '1' ): ?>
                    <span class="verified-badge"><i class="fal fa-check"></i></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </h3>
            <?php //if( $hide_address != 'yes'): 
             $phone = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), ESB_META_PREFIX.'phone', true );    
            ?><?php if($phone != '' ): ?><li class="phone-on-photo"><span><i class="fal fa-phone"></i><?php _e( ' ', 'townhub-add-ons' ); ?></span><a href="tel:<?php echo esc_attr( $phone );?>"><?php echo $phone ?></a>
            <!--<div class="geodir-category-location fl-wrap"><a href="<?php echo $address_url; ?>" class="map-item"  style="color: #000;" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><?php 
                echo townhub_addons_listing_get_address(); 
            ?></a></div>-->
            </li><?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="geodir-category-text fl-wrap">
        <?php 
        // the_excerpt();
        if( $hide_excerpt != 'yes') townhub_addons_the_excerpt_max_charlength( townhub_addons_get_option('excerpt_length','55') );
        ?>
        <?php 
        if( $show_locations == 'yes' ){
            $terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'listing_location', array( "fields" => "ids" ) );
            if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){ 
                $terms = trim( implode( ',', (array) $terms ), ' ,' );
                wp_list_categories( 'style=flat&separator=&title_li=&taxonomy=' . 'listing_location' . '&include=' . $terms );
            }
        } ?>
        <div class="lcfields-wrap dis-flex"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $azp_content ); ?></div>
        <?php 
        if( $hide_features != 'yes'):
        $terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'listing_feature');
        if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){  
        ?>
        <div class="facilities-list fl-wrap dis-flex flw-wrap">
            <div class="facilities-list-title"><?php _e( 'Facilities: ', 'townhub-add-ons' ); ?></div>
            <ul class="no-list-style mrg-0 dis-inflex">
                <?php 
                $count = 1;
                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                    if($count > (int)$num_feature) break;
                    $term_metas = townhub_addons_custom_tax_metas($term->term_id, 'listing_feature'); 
                    //get_term_meta( $term->term_id, ESB_META_PREFIX.'term_meta', true );
                    ?>
                    <li class="tolt"  data-microtip-position="top" data-tooltip="<?php echo esc_attr( $term->name ); ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo townhub_addons_get_term_link( $term->term_id, 'listing_feature' ); ?>"><i class="<?php echo esc_attr( $term_metas['icon'] ); ?>"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                    $count++;
                }
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php } 
        endif;
        $price_from = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_price', true );
        if( $show_price == 'yes' && !empty($price_from) ){
            echo '<div class="lcard-price">'.sprintf(_x( 'Price: <strong>%s</strong>', 'Lcard price', 'townhub-add-ons' ), townhub_addons_get_price_formated($price_from) ).'</div>';
        }
        $price_to = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), ESB_META_PREFIX.'price_to', true );
        if( $show_pricerange == 'yes' && !empty($price_to) ) :  ?>
        <div class="lcard-price lcard-pricerange">
        <?php 
            _ex( 'Price range: ','Listing card', 'townhub-add-ons' );
            echo '<span class="lpricerange-prices"><strong class="lpricerange-from">'.townhub_addons_get_price_formated($price_from).'</strong>';
            if( !empty($price_to) ) echo '<strong class="lpricerange-to">'. sprintf( _x( ' - %s','Listing card', 'townhub-add-ons' ), townhub_addons_get_price_formated($price_to) ) .'</strong>';
            echo '</span>';
        ?>
        </div>
        <?php 
        endif;
        
        global $post;
        if( isset($post->listing_distance) && !empty($post->listing_distance) ){
            echo '<div class="lcard-distance">';
                echo sprintf(_x( 'Distance: <strong>%s km</strong>', 'Lcard distance', 'townhub-add-ons' ), number_format($post->listing_distance,1) );
            echo '</div>';
        }
        do_action( 'cth_listing_card_content' );
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php if( $hide_footer != 'yes' ): ?>
    <div class="geodir-category-footer fl-wrap dis-flex">
        <?php 
        if( $hide_cats != 'yes'){
        $cats = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'listing_cat');
        if ( $cats && ! is_wp_error( $cats ) ){ ?>
            <div class="listing-cats-wrap dis-flex">
                <?php 
                foreach( $cats as $key => $cat){
                    $term_metas = townhub_addons_custom_tax_metas($cat->term_id); 
                    echo sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" class="listing-item-category-wrap flex-items-center">%3$s<span>%2$s</span></a> ',
                        townhub_addons_get_term_link( $cat->term_id, 'listing_cat' ),
                        esc_html( $cat->name ),
                        ($term_metas['icon'] != '' ? '<div class="listing-item-category '.$term_metas['color'].'"><i class="'.$term_metas['icon'].'"></i></div>' : ''),
                        $term_metas['color']
                    );
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        <?php }  
        } ?>
        <?php 
        if( $hide_price_range != 'yes'):
            $price_range = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), ESB_META_PREFIX.'price_range', true ); 
            $prrrate = townhub_addons_get_price_range_rate($price_range);
            if( $prrrate > 0 ):
        ?>
        <div class="price-level geodir-category_price dis-flex">
            <span class="price-level-item" data-pricerating="<?php echo esc_attr( $prrrate ); ?>"></span>
            <span class="price-name-tooltip"><?php echo townhub_addons_get_listing_price_range($price_range, true); ?></span>
        </div>
        <?php endif; 
        endif; ?>
        <div class="geodir-opt-list dis-flex">
            <ul class="no-list-style">
                <?php 
                    // <li class="lcard-bot-view"><i class="fal fa-eye"></i> echo Esb_Class_LStats::get_stats(get_the_ID()); </li>
                ?>
                <?php if( $show_web == 'yes' && !empty($website) ): ?><li class="lcard-bot-web"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $website ); ?>" target="_blank"><i class="fal fa-globe"></i></a></li><?php endif; ?>
                <?php if( $hide_contacts != 'yes'): ?><li class="lcard-bot-infos"><a href="#" class="show_gcc"><i class="fal fa-envelope"></i><span class="geodir-opt-tooltip"><?php _e( 'Contact Info', 'townhub-add-ons' ); ?></span></a></li><?php endif; ?>
                <?php if( $hide_view_map != 'yes' && townhub_addons_get_option('map_provider') == 'googlemap' ): ?><li class="lcard-bot-map"><a href="<?php echo $address_url; ?>" class="map-item" target="_blank"><i class="fal fa-map-marker-alt"></i><span class="geodir-opt-tooltip"><?php _e( 'On the map', 'townhub-add-ons' ); ?></span> </a></li><?php endif; ?>
                
                
                <?php 
                if( $hide_gallery != 'yes'):
                    $images = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), ESB_META_PREFIX.'images', true );
                    if( !empty($images) && !is_array($images) ) { 
                        $images = explode(",", $images);
                        $images_gal = array();
                        foreach ($images as $key => $id) {
                            $images_gal[] = array('src'=> wp_get_attachment_url( $id ));
                        }
                ?>
                <li class="lcard-bot-gallery">
                    <div class="dynamic-gal gdop-list-link" data-dynamicPath='<?php echo json_encode($images_gal);?>'>
                        <i class="fal fa-search-plus"></i><span class="geodir-opt-tooltip"><?php _e( 'Gallery', 'townhub-add-ons' ); ?></span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php } 
                endif; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php
        if( $hide_contacts != 'yes'): 
            $phone = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), ESB_META_PREFIX.'phone', true );
            $email = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), ESB_META_PREFIX.'email', true );
            
            if($phone != '' || $email != '' || $website != '' ):
        ?>
        <div class="geodir-category_contacts">
            <div class="close_gcc"><i class="fal fa-times-circle"></i></div>
            <ul class="no-list-style">
                <?php if($phone != '' ): ?><li><span><i class="fal fa-phone"></i><?php _e( ' Call for owner : ', 'townhub-add-ons' ); ?></span><a href="tel:<?php echo esc_attr( $phone );?>"><?php echo $phone ?></a></li><?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($email != '' ): ?><li><span><i class="fal fa-envelope"></i><?php _e( ' Write : ', 'townhub-add-ons' ); ?></span><a href="mailto:<?php echo esc_attr( $email ); ?>"><?php echo $email ?></a></li><?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($website != '' ): ?><li><span><i class="fal fa-link"></i></span><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $website ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Visit website', 'townhub-add-ons' ); ?></a></li><?php endif; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php endif; 
        endif; 
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php // }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот эта строка  `echo '<div class="lcard-price">'.sprintf(_x( 'Price: <strong>%s</strong>', 'Lcard price', 'townhub-add-ons' ), townhub_addons_get_price_formated($price_from) ).'</div>';` отвечает за вывод цены

Comment: Здравствуйте, я так же думал. Но меняй тут какие-либо данные ничего не происходит.

Comment: Замените ``` sprintf(_x( 'Price: <strong>%s</strong>', 'Lcard price', 'townhub-add-ons' ), townhub_addons_get_price_formated($price_from) ) ```  на любое значение строка и посмотрите что будут

Comment: ``` echo '<div class="lcard-price">'.sprintf(_x( 'Cost: <strong></strong>', 'Lcard price', 'townhub-add-ons' ), townhub_addons_get_price_formated($phone) ).'</div>'; ``` Заменил и ничего не происходит. Только этот код относиться к этой странице.

Comment: Возможно что на сайте установлен кеширующий плагин или сайт отдается с cdn сервера... тогда изменения видны не будут пока не сброситься кеш или не произойдет обновления на сервере. Что бы это проверить необходимо выполнить критическое изменение на странице, если после него страница продолжает отдаваться, то это точно с cdn, и тогда только ребутить кеши